# using spring framework RestClient to call HTTP request is Very slow in signed JAR with JRE 10

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm using

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

URI uriScopeDep;
try {
    uriScopeDep = new URI(scriptUrl);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
    String body = restTemplate.exchange(uriScopeDep, 
    HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
 ...
```

1. I compile with JDK 8, it works fine.
2. I try to run the compiled JDK 8 version on a machine with JRE 8, it works fine.
3. I try on a machine with JRE 10 it works fine.
4. 1 day we decided to use Jar Signer, after the jar got signed (JDK 8),
   it stil worked with JRE 8, but once I upgraded the machine to JRE 10 or run with JRE 10, the HTTP request takes forever.

Calling so many requests in JRE 8 took 30 seconds..
In the JRE 10 it took over 9 minutes!
Can anybody help with the slowness issue?